# An AJAX HTTP error occurred when trying to update Drupal. HTTP Result Code: 403

Tags: docker, nginx, drupal, updating

I am running Drupal along with ISLE on docker on localhost. However, When I try to update Drupal, I receive these errors... Any answers you can provide are greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to set $settings['allow_authorize_operations'] to TRUE.
See this, from default.settings.php

```
/**
 * Authorized file system operations:
 *
 * The Update Manager module included with Drupal provides a mechanism for
 * site administrators to securely install missing updates for the site
 * directly through the web user interface. On securely-configured servers,
 * the Update manager will require the administrator to provide SSH or FTP
 * credentials before allowing the installation to proceed; this allows the
 * site to update the new files as the user who owns all the Drupal files,
 * instead of as the user the webserver is running as. On servers where the
 * webserver user is itself the owner of the Drupal files, the administrator
 * will not be prompted for SSH or FTP credentials (note that these server
 * setups are common on shared hosting, but are inherently insecure).
 *
 * Some sites might wish to disable the above functionality, and only update
 * the code directly via SSH or FTP themselves. This setting completely
 * disables all functionality related to these authorized file operations.
 *
 * @see https://www.drupal.org/node/244924
 *
 * Remove the leading hash signs to disable.
 */
# $settings['allow_authorize_operations'] = FALSE;
```

There is also known bug related to that file path in Drupal 9.4
https://www.drupal.org/node/2583799